# Trying to write to a Hex file(.bin) using PB12.5 using BlobEdit (Blob)

Tags: binary, hex, blob, powerbuilder

I'm trying to write to a hex file using PB12.5, I'm able to write to it without any issues but through testing noticed I will need to send a null value (00) to the file at certain points.

I know if I assign null to a string, it will null out the entire string so I tried using a Blob where I can insert a null value when needed (BlobEdit(blb_data, ll_pos, CharA(0)) )

But BlobEdit() automatically inserts a null value in between each position, I don't want this as it's causing issues as I'm trying to update the hex file.  I just need to add my CharA(lb_byte) to each consecutive position in the Blob.

Is there any way around this or is PB just unable to do this?  Below is the code:

```
    ll_test = 1
    ll_pos = 1
    ll_length = Len(ls_output)
    Do While ll_pos <= (ll_length)
        ls_data = Mid(ls_output, ll_pos, 2)
        lb_byte = Event ue_get_decimal_value_of_hex(ls_data)
        ll_test = BlobEdit(blb_data, ll_test, CharA(lb_byte), EncodingANSI!)
        ll_pos = ll_pos + 2
    Loop
```

Hex file appears as follows:

```
    16 35 2D D8 08 45 29 18 35 27 76 25 30 55 66 85 44 66 57 A4 67 99
```

After Blob update:

```
    16 00 48 00 5D 00 C3 92 00 08 00 48 00 51 00 E2
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope to help you:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function: f_longtohex
// Description: LONG to HEXADECIMAL
//  Ambito: public
//  Argumentos:     as_number   //Variable long to convert to hexadecimal
//              as_digitos  //Number of digits to return
//  Return:         String      
//  Example: 
//              f_longtohex(198 , 2)    --> 'C6'
//              f_longtohex(198 , 4)    --> '00C6'
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
long ll_temp0, ll_temp1 
char lc_ret 
if isnull(as_digitos) then as_digitos = 2
IF as_digitos > 0 THEN 
    ll_temp0 = abs(as_number / (16 ^ (as_digitos - 1))) 
    ll_temp1 = ll_temp0 * (16 ^ (as_digitos - 1)) 
    IF ll_temp0 > 9 THEN 
        lc_ret = char(ll_temp0 + 55) 
    ELSE 
        lc_ret = char(ll_temp0 + 48) 
    END IF 
    RETURN lc_ret + f_longtohex(as_number - ll_temp1 , as_digitos - 1) 
END IF 
RETURN ''
```